# Node.js Readable Stream _read Usage

Tags: node.js, stream, udp

I understand how to use writable streams in Node's new `Streams2` library, but I don't understand how to use readable streams.

Take, for example, a stream wrapper around the `dgram` module:

```
var dgram = require('dgram');

var thumbs = {
  twiddle: function() {}
};

var defaults = {
  address: '0.0.0.0',
  type: 'udp4',
  port: 12345,
  broadcast: null,
  multicast: null,
  multicastTTL: 1
};

var UDPStream = function(options) {
  if (!(this instanceof UDPStream))
    return new UDPStream(options);

  Duplex.call(this);

  options = options || {};

  this.address = options.address || defaults.address;
  this.type = options.type || defaults.type;
  this.port = options.port || defaults.port;
  this.broadcast = options.broadcast || defaults.broadcast;
  this.multicast = options.multicast || defaults.multicast;
  this.multicastTTL = options.multicastTTL || defaults.multicastTTL;

  this._socket = dgram.createSocket(this.type, setup.bind(this));
  this._socket.on('message', this.push.bind(this));
};

util.inherits(UDPStream, Duplex);

var setup = function() {
  if (this.multicast) {
    this._socket.addMembership(this.multicast);
    this._socket.setMulticastTTL(this.multicastTTL);

    this.destination = this.multicast;
  } else {
    // default to using broadcast if multicast address is not specified.
    this._socket.setBroadcast(true);

    // TODO: get the default broadcast address from os.networkInterfaces() (not currently returned)
    this.destination = this.broadcast || '255.255.255.255';
  }
};

UDPStream.prototype._read = function(size) {
  thumbs.twiddle();
};

UDPStream.prototype._write = function(chunk, encoding, callback) {
  this._socket.send(chunk, 0, chunk.length, this.port, this.destination);
  callback();
};

module.exports = UDPStream;
```

Everything makes sense except for the `_read` implementation. It's literally twiddling thumbs because I don't understand what I'm supposed to do there. My data is pushed when the udp socket emits a new message, but I have no way of pausing or resuming the underlying resource. What *should* this look like?

Comment: Bonus question: how should `close` and `error` events be handled?

Comment: Any comments to this? I'm also confused with the implementation of readable streams when using a tcp/udp source that cannot be paused. Right now I'm simply ignoring the _read function and the highWaterMark value, and I'm also ignoring the boolean value returned by push(). If it returns false, I continue pushing more data chunks because the stream can handle it ([fromList() function](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_stream_readable.js))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is fairly straightforward: if there is truly no way to apply backpressure to your underlying resource, your `_read` implementation is simply empty. The stream will take care of queueing your pushed data until it hits the `highWaterMark`, but guarantees nothing beyond that point. [The docs](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_read_size_1) say that you should "simply provide data whenever it becomes available."

Answer (score 0):

_read is part of the pause resume mechanism. From the NodeJS API docs

> When data is available, put it into the read queue by calling
>   readable.push(chunk). If push returns false, then you should stop
>   reading. When _read is called again, you should start pushing more
>   data.

So in your _write function, if the `socket.send` call fails by either returning false or calling a callback with an error you should pause your stream. `_read` then can simple do `this._paused = false`

Might look like this.

```
UDPStream.prototype._read = function() {
  this._paused = false;
}

UDPStream.prototype._write = function(chunk, encoding, callback) {
  if(!this._paused)
   this._socket.send(chunk, 0, chunk.length, this.port, this.destination);
};
```

Comment: A duplex stream is a representation of an readable channel and an writable channel. These channels are more or less independent, and it doesn't make sense to me that the `_read` method, specified in the `Readable` "class" and therefore part of the "readable" channel, would influence the `_write` method, specified in the `Writable` "class" and therefore part of the "writable" channel. Furthermore, I suspect you're confusing `_socket.send` and `push` in your interpretation of the API docs.